# Android button bar toggle

Tags: android, button, user-interface, toggle

I am looking for a UI view that imitates the functionality of the
Google Maps directions screen UI control where it allows the user to
pick the type of directions allowed, either Car, Transit or Walking.

Like this --> http://snapplr.com/50rh

The widget is essentially three buttons laid out horizontally with
rounded corners only on the left of the first and right of the thirdbutton.

I can't see a standard way to do this, although it seems like it would
be a common widget.  Is there some other standard way of presenting a
multi-choice grouping in a horizontal layout as a "single" layout
object.

Comment: Did you manage to find something like this? I am looking for it too, but I wouldn't need the images as label, just text. Strange that there isn't such a widget already.

Comment: I too am looking for a solution to this problem.  Anyone have a widget for this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a button bar widget in the Android SDK. You would create one with `ImageButtons` in a `LinearLayout`, with custom backgrounds for all (to give the gloss-black look, to handle the varied sets of corners, and to handle the selected vs. not imagery). You would then need to add the toggling smarts, such that pushing one makes it selected and makes the others in the layout not selected.

If you wish to stick to simpler existing widgets, `Spinner`, `RadioButton`, or `ToggleButton` would be the most likely candidates.

Comment: OK thank you for the information.. I will try it with ImageButtons. But I hope Google will release a widget for this so this would be easier to develop!

Wouter

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built-in way to do it.  I can think of two ways to accomplish it.  The first would be to create a custom style for the TabWidget.  The second would be to create your own custom widget.  Making a TabWidget style might be more flexible because you could easily come back and add or remove tabs and it would update accordingly.  Making your own custom widget would give you much more control over how the widget looks and acts.  So really you need to see what would be the best fit for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I haven't tried using `TabWidget` outside of actual tabs. It's an interesting concept!

Comment: I just tried it and using the TabWidget outside of a TabHost doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the power control widget does what you want. Looking at the source for the widget, it uses a combination of LinearLayouts & ImageViews to achieve the layout.

Layout file: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/froyo-release/res/layout/widget.xml

Source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/froyo-release/src/com/android/settings/widget/SettingsAppWidgetProvider.java

Answer (score 0):

Best button bar I've found: http://androidworkz.com/2011/02/04/custom-menu-bar-tabs-how-to-hook-the-menu-button-to-showhide-a-custom-tab-bar/

It's thought to be used as a replacement for the menu, but I believe it's also great for a custom button bar. I'm actually gonna integrate it in my app straight away :-)

Kudos for androidworkz, the original author.